# Python: Efficient way to call inbuilt function multiple times?

Tags: python, performance, function

I have a code that looks something like this:

```
def somefunction(somelist):
    for item in somelist:
        if len(item) > 10:
            do something
        elif len(item) > 6:
            do something
        elif len(item) > 3:
            do something
        else:
            do something
```

Since I am calling len(item) multiple times, is it inefficient to do it this way? Would it be preferable to write the code as follows, or are they EXACTLY the same in performance?

```
def somefunction(somelist):
    for item in somelist:
        x = len(item)
        if x > 10:
            do something
        elif x > 6:
            do something
        elif x > 3:
            do something
        else:
            do something
```

Comment: Is `item` a `list`? If it is, the length is already stored so the only cost will be the function name lookup which would have a microscopic impact.

Comment: I would argue the second is much better - not because of speed (which will barely ever matter) - but because it's easier to read and write. Who wants to be typing out `len(item)` a ton of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second approach is surely better, as the number of calls to `len()` are reduced:

```
In [16]: import dis

In [18]: lis=["a"*10000,"b"*10000,"c"*10000]*1000

In [19]: def first():
    for item in lis:
        if len(item)<100:
            pass
        elif 100<len(item)<200:
            pass
        elif 300<len(item)<400:
            pass
   ....:         

In [20]: def second():
    for item in lis:
        x=len(item)
        if x<100:
                pass
        elif 100<x<200:
                pass
        elif 300<x<400:
                pass
   ....:
```

You can always time your code using `timeit` module:

```
In [21]: %timeit first()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.03 ms per loop

In [22]: %timeit second()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.66 ms per loop
```

Use `dis.dis()` to see disassembling of Python byte code into mnemonics

```
In [24]: dis.dis(first)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP             109 (to 112)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (lis)
              6 GET_ITER            
        >>    7 FOR_ITER               101 (to 111)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (item)

  3          13 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
             25 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             28 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       34

  4          31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7

  5     >>   34 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
             37 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             40 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
             43 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             46 DUP_TOP             
             47 ROT_THREE           
             48 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             51 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    63
             54 LOAD_CONST               2 (200)
             57 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             60 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 65)
        >>   63 ROT_TWO             
             64 POP_TOP             
        >>   65 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       71

  6          68 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7

  7     >>   71 LOAD_CONST               3 (300)
             74 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             77 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
             80 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             83 DUP_TOP             
             84 ROT_THREE           
             85 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             88 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP   100
             91 LOAD_CONST               4 (400)
             94 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             97 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 102)
        >>  100 ROT_TWO             
            101 POP_TOP             
        >>  102 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        7

  8         105 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
            108 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>  111 POP_BLOCK           
        >>  112 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            115 RETURN_VALUE        

In [25]: dis.dis(second)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP             103 (to 106)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (lis)
              6 GET_ITER            
        >>    7 FOR_ITER                95 (to 105)
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (item)

  3          13 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (len)
             16 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
             19 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  4          25 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             28 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
             31 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             34 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       40

  5          37 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7

  6     >>   40 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
             43 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             46 DUP_TOP             
             47 ROT_THREE           
             48 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             51 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    63
             54 LOAD_CONST               2 (200)
             57 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             60 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 65)
        >>   63 ROT_TWO             
             64 POP_TOP             
        >>   65 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       71

  7          68 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7

  8     >>   71 LOAD_CONST               3 (300)
             74 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             77 DUP_TOP             
             78 ROT_THREE           
             79 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             82 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    94
             85 LOAD_CONST               4 (400)
             88 COMPARE_OP               0 (<)
             91 JUMP_FORWARD             2 (to 96)
        >>   94 ROT_TWO             
             95 POP_TOP             
        >>   96 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE        7

  9          99 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
            102 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            7
        >>  105 POP_BLOCK           
        >>  106 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            109 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

len() is [O(1)](http://books.google.co.th/books?id=JnR9hQA3SncC&pg=PA478&dq=Python%2blen%2bbig%2bO&ei=JUbRSYPqGofqkwTy9_ihAQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Python%2blen%2bbig%2bO&f=false) operation. This mean the cost of calling [len( )](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) is very cheap. So, stop worrying about it and better improve other part of your code.

However, personally, I think the second way is better. Because if I change your variable name from `x` to `length`, it will increase your code's readability.

```
def somefunction(somelist):
    for item in somelist:
        length = len(item)
        if length > 10:
            do something
        elif length > 6:
            do something
        elif length > 3:
            do something
        else:
            do something
```

**NOTE:** `len( )` is O(1) with strings, sets, and dictionaries.

Comment: This is only true on lists, on other objects, `len()` could be anything at all.

Comment: @Lattyware Thank you for adding that. I totally forgot to mention it. I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't optimize things automatically like most other languages (unless you're using PyPy), so the second version is probably faster. But unless `item` has a custom `len` implementation that takes a while, it probably won't speed things up that much either. This is the sort of microoptimization that should be reserved for tight inner loops after profiling has indicated a problem.

Comment: *Python doesn't optimize things automatically like most other languages* is a bit of a wide statement, Python does plenty of optimizations, but the language is so flexible and dynamic, some optimizations that are trivial for other languages are not possible, or are less efficient/require a much less simple implementation, etc...

Comment: @Lattyware, but it can still be optimized with a JIT compiler (like Pypy). Being dynamic didn't stop Javascript's V8. However, Cpython is still the most common Python implementation, and it doesn't do much optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You can check such things with `dis.dis`:

```
import dis

def somefunction1(item):
    if len(item) > 10:
        print 1
    elif len(item) > 10:
        print 2

def somefunction2(item):
    x = len(item)
    if x > 10:
        print 1
    elif x > 10:
        print 2

print "#1"
dis.dis(somefunction1)

print "#2"
dis.dis(somefunction2)
```

Interpreting the output:

```
#1
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             12 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             15 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       26
[...]
  6     >>   26 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
             29 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
             32 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             35 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             38 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             41 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       52
[...]
#2
 10           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (len)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (item)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

 11          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             18 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             21 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       32
[...]
 13     >>   32 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             35 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             38 COMPARE_OP               4 (>)
             41 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       52
```

You can see that in the first example, `len(item)` is called twice (see the two `CALL_FUNCTION` statements?), whereas it is only called one in the second implementation.

This means that the rest of your question boils down to how `len()` is implemented -- it is O(1) (ie. cheap) for e.g. lists, but especially for ones you might have built yourself, it need not be.

Answer (score 1):

Python does not make the two equivalent. The reason being that the two are not equivalent for an arbitrary function. Let's consider this function, `x()`:

```
y = 1

def x():
    return 1
```

And these two tests:

```
>>> print(x() + y)
2
>>> print(x() + y)
2
```

And:

```
>>> hw = x()
>>> print(hw + y)
2
>>> print(hw + y)
2
```

These are exactly the same, however, what if our function has side effects?

```
y = 1

def x():
    global y
    y += 1
    return 1
```

The first case:

```
>>> print(x() + y)
3
>>> print(x() + y)
4
```

The second case:

```
>>> hw = x()
>>> print(hw + y)
3
>>> print(hw + y)
3
```

You can see that this optimization only works if the function has no side-effects, otherwise it can alter the program. As Python can't tell if a function has side-effects, it can't do this optimization.

As such, it makes sense to store the value locally and use it repeatedly, rather than calling the function again and again, although the reality is it is highly unlikely to matter as the difference will be tiny. That said, it's also much more readable and means you don't have to repeat yourself a lot, so it's generally a good idea to code that way.